# How can I destroy earth with physics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, earth

I want to destroy the whole earth using physics, I would like to learn some of the ways that can be used to achieve this. I tried using a nuclear bomb but it takes so long, and I can't wait that much: [Why does it take so long to make a nuclear bomb?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68156/why-does-it-take-so-long-to-make-a-nuclear-bomb)

What are some physics experiments and theories to help me destroy the earth? Note that I have all the money and privileges I need.

Comment: Your question isn't clear: you need to define "destroy".  Is it sufficient to leave the Earth physically intact and ruin the geological landscape?  or do you mean that it has to be shattered into a million pieces?

Comment: @QuantumDot no it should be shattered into a million pieces.

Comment: Send a space crew to divert an asteroid onto the earth.

Comment: I don't think you need physics to do this. Politics is doing it just fine.

Comment: You'll need a [Death Star](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efFl_EDXCW0)

Comment: Why was this upvoted?

Comment: That's a boring question; you can't destroy the earth *without* using physics!

Comment: Find a planet made of anti - matter and let it collide with earth

Comment: If you can't wait that much maybe you don't have the willpower to destroy earth anyway

Comment: If you have all the money and privileges you need, why would you be looking for *free* advice here?  I would think that someone in your position would have already developed an elaborate network of the best evil scientists to be found.

Comment: Is this question hypothetical, or do you really want to destroy the Earth?  Because if you are, you might want to go to a nice padded room.

Comment: Last December, I received a text message from the USGS which said there had been an earthquake near Polson, Montana with a magnitude of 22.0. My first thought was that the Solar System would have a new asteroid belt, but my calculations indicated that there probably wouldn't be enough left to form one; the energy released would be about 250,000 times Earth's gravitational binding energy, more than enough to vaporize the planet. Unfortunately for your evil schemes, a followup message revised the magnitude to 2.2.

Answer (score 3):

Earth's gravitational binding energy is $-1.711×10^{32}~\mathrm{J}$ or $4.09×10^{13}$ gigatons. The Tsar Bomba massed $27$ tonnes to deliver $0.057$ gigatons. Do the math for Earth disassembly by bomb. Substituting depleted uranium for the used lead tamper will double the yield.

Earth orbital speed averages 30 km/s and it masses $5.97×10^{24}~\mathrm{kg}$, so $mv^2 / 2 = 2.7×10^{33}~\mathrm{J}$.
Rather than going for a messy asteroid impact and endangering Venusian hortas with debris infall, drop the Earth into the Sun, $t = 64.56$ days.

Patience. The Earth's rotational energy is about $2.13 \times 10^{29}~\mathrm{J}$ (non-homogeneous sphere). You'll need obtain the orbital stopper energy elsewhere.

The fast path is simply to drop a strangelet. The Earth will condense into "an inert hyperdense sphere about one hundred meters across."

http://typnet.net/Essays/EarthBind.htm 
http://phys.org/news/2014-02-chances-particle-collider-strangelets-earth.html