# Why is it necessary to enrich Uranium and Plutonium before they can be used in nuclear warheads?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

The World Nuclear Association(WNA) states:

> [Weapons-grade](http://www.world-nuclear.org/information-library/nuclear-fuel-cycle/uranium-resources/military-warheads-as-a-source-of-nuclear-fuel.aspx) uranium is highly enriched, to over 90% U-235 (the
>   fissile isotope).Weapons-grade plutonium has over 93% Pu-239

However, what WNA or any other nuclear weapon watchdog do not state is why Uranium or Plutonium is **enriched** in the first case before they can be used in nuclear warheads?

Is it because the amount of space available in the warhead is limited and therefore only a small amount of Uranium or Plutonium can be used & so they have to be enriched first?

Comment: Of the top of my head, $U_{235}$ is fissured by neutrons, and then emits more neutrons when fissured. I believe $U_{238}$ absorbs the emitted neutrons, without fissuring. To ensure we have a constant supply of neutrons, we have to ensure that most of our neutrons are not absorbed by $U_{238}$, so we have to enrich our uranium to have more $U_{235}$.

Comment: People are listening...

Comment: Very closely related: [Why does it take so long to make a nuclear bomb?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68156/why-does-it-take-so-long-to-make-a-nuclear-bomb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weapons grade $U$ has to be highly enriched to boost its levels of $U^{235}$ from the natural level (about 0.7 w%) to > 90 w%. That's because $U^{235}$ is the fissionable isotope and its concentration in the bomb core has to be sufficiently high for an explosive nuclear chain reaction to be able to occur.

Weapons grade $Pu$ is not obtained by enrichment. It is obtained by irradiating $U^{238}$ with neutrons in purpose-built (non-civilian) nuclear reactors. There, neutron capture then converts $U^{238}$ to $Pu^{239}$ which is the fissionable isotope of $Pu$. Irradiation conditions and times are carefully chosen so that $Pu^{239}$ is almost the only $Pu$ isotope formed in the process.

After the irradiation process (aka 'breeding process') the $Pu$ is then *chemically* separated from the $U$ (and other isotopes). $Pu$ obtained in this way is typically higher than 93 w% $Pu^{239}$ and does not require enrichment.

Comment: Thank You! So, when you say  `That's because U235 is the fissionable isotope and its concentration in the bomb core has to be sufficiently high for an explosive nuclear chain reaction to be able to occur` what's the quantity of  U235 that is needed in the bomb core?

Comment: @D_S: it's not clear. Literature numbers vary from 80 w% to 95 w%. In theory, the higher the better but enrichment is very expensive, so I guess there's a trade-off there.

Comment: The amount of critical mass required to ensure a chain reaction depends on a number of factors.  The shape of the critical assembly is one.  If the assembly is composed of two sub-critical masses which are combined rapidly using implosion, there may be a reduction in the total amount of fissile material used versus say a gun-type assembly method used in the first A-bomb.