# Why it took such a long time for an army of physicists to realize the atomic bomb, while in theory it seems pretty easy?

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, nuclear-engineering, explosions

I think most of us know about the construction of the first atomic bomb at [Los Alamos](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Alamos_National_Laboratory), with [Robert Oppenheimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Robert_Oppenheimer) (who said he became "The destroyer of worlds", which goes to show he regretted his participation; nevertheless he **did** participate) in charge of an enormous complex where many, many brilliant physicists (including Feynman) were offered (ordered for participating in?) a well-paid job, housing, food and drink, etc. The project was initiated by Einstein after sending a letter to Roosevelt (correct me if I'm wrong), which seems to contradict his pacifist attitude. But that's not that relevant to my question. Which is:

Why it took such a long time (2-3 years) for all these men (and some women), working on that enormous complex, to construct an actual working device [the first test (called the [Trinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_(nuclear_test)) nuclear test) hit the jackpot], while in principle you "just" have to smash together two masses of Plutonium below the critical mass, which after the smash have a mass above that mass? That **was** known (i.e. in theory) at the time. Was it because it was the beginning of the atomic era, and there was still much to learn? Was it to prevent failure? I've read many times the Nazis were on the verge of constructing one too, and I suppose the Americans knew that too. So why not hurry a bit more? "Luckily", the Americans were first, though there were two dropped on Japan since Germany had already surrendered. Even a third was planned to be thrown because there could be used three different elements in the bomb, and the Americans wanted to see how all three exploded. The second one, dropped on Nagasaki, was i.m.o. totally superfluous.

Comment: FYI there is a [History of Science Stackexchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) where this question might be a better fit.

Comment: Short answer: the most time consuming aspect was separating the fissile isotopes from raw ore. Designing the implosive device also stretched the capabilities of engineering at the time.

Comment: They knew they had to combine two sub-critical masses to make a critical mass. They didn't know at the start just how much was the critical mass.

Comment: Did the calculation of the critical mass take thát long?  You can't do experiments to find out how big the critical mass is...BOOM!!

Comment: I think I found the answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68156/  so case closed!

Comment: They did do experiments. They called it "tickling the dragon's tail" IIRC. They got close enough to criticality to see the reaction start to increase in rate, then backed off.

Comment: FYI, Physicist/SciFi writer Greg Benford's most recent book, *The Berlin Project*, is an alternate history in which they listen to a junior scientist (who in real life is Benford's father-in-law) who had an idea of a better way to do the U235 separation (which in real life wasn't pursued). Resulting in getting the bomb early enough to use against Germany. Quite a bit of background about the purification process is presumably close to reality.

Comment: It's the first time I hear about "tickling the dragon's tail", but I can imagine why the experiment is called like that. It's a pity I didn't know about the book. It would have been a great Christmas gift (to me)! After Christmas, I'm surely gonna look for it. I'm going to sleep now. Here in Holland, it's five in the morning (5:00 AM ?; AM and PM always confuse me; I know the A stands for Ante and the P for Post, but never remember if the M stands for nighttime or daytime). So goodnight and thanks for your very nice info. And of course a Merry Christmas (if you care about it)!

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/66864-in-theory-theory-and-practice-are-the-same-in-practice (The "m" stands, I seem to recall, for *meridian*, meaning the high point of the sky.)

Comment: Things take time.   The 'in theory it was pretty easy' comment is odd; have you ever  calculated an explosion from first principles, never having seen one?

Comment: Well, if you have calculated the critical mass (which seems to me not thát difficult), you can be pretty sure that when you're in posses of two pieces of the explosive (both of which are below the critical mass but put together above that mass) and smash them together  a BOOM will follow. I agree though that it's very difficult to calculate what the explosion looks like if you've never seen one of that new kind.

Comment: @dmckee-I agree with that, but the highest point in the sky is always to see, so is there a time coupled to this meridian (I haven't read your link yet)?

Comment: Here in The Netherlands (Holland), it's now one o'clock in the daytime. I think that 1:00 PM. So maybe one hour after the highest point of the sun (which we can't see now because it's fully overcast; and no white Christmas here, of which I dreamt so many times...). My girl is calling me to eat the Christmas "breakfast". GGRRRRRR....

Comment: @descheleschilder - M stands for "meridiem" which is Latin (accusative) meaning "midday" (middag). Prettig Kerstfeest!

Comment: *"which seems to me not thát difficult"* Well, let's see. It depends on the (energy-dependent) fission cross-section ;the branching ratios to different numbers of neutrons in the final state, the energy distributions of the neutrons in each state, the rate of diffusive moderation, and critically on the geometry (a 'critical mass' in one shape can be sub-critical in another). You *can't* do the general problem as a white-board calculation, but *must* do it in Monte Carlo (conducted with dice, pencils, trolleys and protractors for the Manhattan project!).

Comment: I placed the question on the History Of Science StackExchange, where ZeroTheHero gave the best answer (for me). https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/why-it-took-an-army-of-physicists-working-on-a-huge-complex-so-long-to-produce/6839#6839   It has about the same content as in your comment (but more elaborated), so I think that you know why I gave you an upvote for your comment. Nice to write Prettig Kerstfeest by the way, and now I know what exactly the m  stands for. Also for you: Prettig Kerstfeest!

Comment: @freecharly-I accidentally thought it was dmckee who said **Prettig Kerstfeest**. That's why I say to you now: **Gelukkig Nieuwjaar!**

Comment: @descheleschilder:  Calculating the critical mass in the presence of contamination by unknown amounts of isotopes, when the reaction CREATES new isotopes, is fiendishly difficult.   The German program never discovered that published data on graphite was wrong (and predicted failure of graphite-moderated chain reaction), and it was wrong because commercial graphite had  small  boron content.

Answer (score 9):

AS you say, by the time the Manhattan project began in earnest, the fundamental principles were extremely clear. The length of development time needed was owing to predominantly technical hurdles, not predominantly lack of physics knowledge:

1. A relatively minor problem was the lack of computing power, which hindered the development of models that would foretell critical masses and also the hydrodynamics of the explosion itself. The latter governs how swiftly the potential bomb breaks itself apart thus quenching the reaction. This problem was overcome simply by the development of simple analytical models for symmetrical systems that did not deviate in shape from the final bomb too much;
2. The first major problem was the purification of uranium to enrich it enough to allow a chain reaction - only $^{235}{\rm U}$ is fissile. There were no current technologies that could separate isotopes on the scale required and these had to be developed pretty much from scratch;
3. The second major problem, once enough plutonium came on hand (plutonium is relatively easy to separate chemically from spent uranium fuel) was the presence of $^{241}{\rm Pu}$. There was no workable technology for removing this "contaminant". $^{241}{\rm Pu}$ is highly radioactive and, if present in a gun type weapon slug (as it inevitably is), its decay products will trigger the nuclear chain reaction far too early as the subcritical masses are thrust together, unless this happens with stupendously high speed. The potential bomb thus blows itself swiftly asunder quenching the reaction. At first the "tall man" design of bomb was tried, which the researchers thought was long enough to accelerate the subcritical slug enough to assemble the critical mass quickly enough. However, this proved impracticable, at least for a bomb that might be delivered by an aircraft. The only alternative that could assemble the critical mass fast enough was the [implosion idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Man), but to make this work the plutonium has to be compressed extremely uniformly, otherwise the crushed core bulges out sideways and criticality will not be reached. There was a huge amount of technology involved in using explosives to yield perfectly spherical shock waves; this had never before been done.
4. All of the above technologies required radical new measurement technologies to be developed so that experimental data could be gleaned. New high speed photographic techniques had to be developed (see the [Rapatronic technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapatronic_camera), for example), and near GHz bandwidth measurement electronics. Neither of these things existed before the project.

One could compare this situation with something like the [quest for a sustained fusion reaction today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITER), and the huge technological problems it poses. The fundamental physics is perfectly clear and the hurdles are wholly technological.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that back then this was all completely new territory for them. They were working with materials that they knew could have killed them all if they got it wrong. They didn't have the benefit of hindsight that we have now.

And it may seem like it's just smashing two masses together but they were making an incredibly complex bomb, meaning it needed to be carefully planned and built with materials that didn't exist before. You don't want the thing going off while you're trying to load it on the plane or in mid flight. With that logic we could say that making a tower is just stacking material on top of each other but how much you plan and design it determines if it's just a tall pile of metal and concrete that could fall down at any time or a reliable sky scraper that people live and work in.

Comment: **They didn't have the benefit of hindsight that we have now.** That's a very good point!